# Count number of points (from two datasets) contained by neighbourhood polygons using PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have three spatial datasets:

1. Neighbourhood polygons
2. Point locations of police stations
3. Point location of crimes

[image]

I am using PostGIS.

The code I currently have is:

```
SELECT 
nc.nbh_names,
count(ps), 
count(ci)
FROM public."Neighborhood_Clusters" AS nc
LEFT JOIN public."Police_Stations" AS ps
ON ST_Contains(nc.geom, ps.geom)
JOIN public."Crime_Incidents_in_2020" AS ci
ON ST_Contains(nc.geom, ci.geom)
GROUP BY nc.nbh_names;
```

The output I am getting:

[image]

I would like my output to be a view that looks like the following:

**Column 1: Neighbourhood name | Column 2: Number of police stations | Column 3: Number of crimes**

There should be no more than one or two police stations per neighbourhood.

It looks like for whatever reason, if there is a police station in the neighborhood, it counts and returns the number of crimes instead.

Can someone please help correct the code so that I get the desired result?

Comment: Can you add a few data samples and the exact output you expect?

Comment: @JimJones I have made some updates. Hope it is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial joins with counts involving multiple tables can get really tricky. What you can do instead is to use a subquery for each table, and then use [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) making reference to the outer query, e.g.

```
SELECT 
   nc.nbh_names,
  (SELECT count(ps.geom) FROM public.Police_Stations ps 
   WHERE ST_Contains(nc.geom, ps.geom)) AS pol,
  (SELECT count(ci.geom) FROM public.Crime_Incidents_in_2020 ci
   WHERE ST_Contains(nc.geom, ci.geom)) AS cri
FROM public.Neighborhood_Clusters nc;
```

Check this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8f036aad92b901195bb132c9543ef789).

Further reading:

- [`Subqueries in PostgreSQL`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-subquery/)
- [`Don't use double quotes in PostgreSQL`](https://lerner.co.il/2013/11/30/quoting-postgresql/)